# Upload the last conversation Power Virtual Agents

Tags: javascript, power-virtual-agents

I am integrating a power virtual gents canvas app using an enpoint, what happens is that when I refresh or go to a second page, it reloads with a new conversation.
How can I get him to keep the conversation going? My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contoso Sample Web Chat</title> 
    <!-- This styling is for the Web Chat demonstration purposes. It is recommended that style is moved to a separate file for organization in larger projects -->
    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="heading">
            <!-- Change the h1 text to change the bot name -->    
            <h1>Contoso Bot Name</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    </div>    
  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
  <script>
        const styleOptions = {

           // Add styleOptions to customize Web Chat canvas
           hideUploadButton: true
        };
        // Add your BOT token endpoint below
        const theURL = "";

        var environmentEndPoint = theURL.slice(0,theURL.indexOf('/powervirtualagents'));
        var apiVersion = theURL.slice(theURL.indexOf('api-version')).split('=')[1];
        var regionalChannelSettingsURL = `${environmentEndPoint}/powervirtualagents/regionalchannelsettings?api-version=${apiVersion}`; 

        var directline;
            fetch(regionalChannelSettingsURL)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                    })
                .then((data) => {
                    directline = data.channelUrlsById.directline;
                    })
                .catch(err => console.error("An error occurred: " + err));

      fetch(theURL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(conversationInfo => {
                window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                    {
                        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
                            domain: `${directline}v3/directline`,
                            token: conversationInfo.token,
                        }),
                        styleOptions
                    },
                    document.getElementById('webchat')
                );
            })
            .catch(err => console.error("An error occurred: " + err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Suggestions and recommendations